# rxjs_1.fromEvent is not a function at new NgbTypeahead

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ng-bootstrap

I am using Angualr5, `rxjs 5.5.11`, `ng-bootstrap 2.0.0`.
If I add [ngbTypeahead] on a html element, I will get the error below：

ERROR TypeError:

> rxjs_1.fromEvent is not a function
>       at new NgbTypeahead (typeahead.js:66)

Comment: Can you please add your code to the question?

Comment: I added the code below:

import * as rxjs from 'rxjs';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs/observable/fromEvent'
rxjs.fromEvent = fromEvent;




but got someelse error:





ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
    at NgbTypeahead.ngOnInit (typeahead.js:85)

Answer (score 0):

This almost always means issues with `import`. You should have one of following:
`import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent'`
or
`import {fromEvent} from 'rxjs/observable/fromEvent'`
or just for test:
`import 'rxjs/Rx';`

However, without any code snippet this is just a lucky guess...

Comment: fromEvent exist in rxjs_1.Observable, but not rxjs_1.